# I am using react-native-vosk package for speech recognition but how can I run it in background to listen continuously

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, vosk

I am using this pacakge'react-native-vosk'
but the issue is I can't run this listener in background

Answer (score 0):

You can't run speech recognition in the background. Only possible if user has the app active.